# Intermittent 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' over network share

Tags: python, file, network-share

I'm running several scripts which are writing and reading from the same CSV file over a network share.

I'm getting intermittent `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.csv'` (every minute or two, with writing/reading every 10-30 seconds), but most of the time the file writing/reading works fine.

Is there any way to track which script has the file open when, and get some more details about the error? I.e. is file in use? Is it losing connection to the file server?

---

### Using Process monitor:

**Ordinary operation (no error messages):**

```
2:33:52.4823608 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryDeviceInformationVolume, DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
2:33:52.4823848 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryDeviceInformationVolume, DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
2:33:52.4824062 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION filename.csv    BUFFER OVERFLOW Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 1/1/1601 8:00:00 AM, VolumeSerialNumber: D020-FD78, SupportsObjects: False, VolumeLabel: DAT`
2:33:52.4827061 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    BUFFER OVERFLOW Type: QueryAllInformationFile, CreationTime: 4/24/2012 2:36:07 PM, LastAccessTime: 4/24/2012 2:36:07 PM, LastWriteTime: 4/24/2012 2:36:07 PM, ChangeTime: 4/24/2012 2:36:07 PM, FileAttributes: A, AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 118,342, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False, IndexNumber: 0x45060de, EaSize: 0, Access: None, Position: 0, Mode: , AlignmentRequirement: Byte
2:33:52.4837725 PM  python.exe  2668    FASTIO_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    FAST IO DISALLOWED  Type: QueryStandardInformationFile
2:33:52.4837820 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryStandardInformationFile, AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 118,342, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
2:33:52.4841324 PM  python.exe  2668    FASTIO_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    FAST IO DISALLOWED  Type: QueryStandardInformationFile
2:33:52.4841458 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryStandardInformationFile, AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 118,342, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
2:33:52.4844948 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    SUCCESS Offset: 117,318, Length: 1,024
2:33:52.4857179 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    END OF FILE Offset: 118,342, Length: 4,096
2:33:52.4862472 PM  python.exe  2668    FASTIO_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    FAST IO DISALLOWED  Type: QueryStandardInformationFile
2:33:52.4862564 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryStandardInformationFile, AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 118,342, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
2:33:52.4867251 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    SUCCESS Offset: 116,294, Length: 1,024
2:33:52.4873473 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    SUCCESS Offset: 117,318, Length: 512
2:33:52.4878825 PM  python.exe  2668    FASTIO_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    FAST IO DISALLOWED  Type: QueryStandardInformationFile
2:33:52.4878917 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION        filename.csv    SUCCESS Type: QueryStandardInformationFile, AllocationSize: 1,048,576, EndOfFile: 118,342, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
2:33:52.4882153 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    SUCCESS Offset: 115,270, Length: 1,024
2:33:52.4889601 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_READ                     filename.csv    SUCCESS Offset: 116,294, Length: 512
2:33:52.4895164 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP                  filename.csv    SUCCESS 
2:33:52.4895513 PM  python.exe  2668    IRP_MJ_CLOSE                    filename.csv    SUCCESS
```

**File open in another program (Errno 13 - Permission Denied):**

```
1:12:42.0840918 PM  python.exe  5772    IRP_MJ_CREATE   filename.csv    SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: 0
```

**Misc error** (not sure if this corresponds to a python error or not)

```
2:57:59.9371101 PM  python.exe  3584    IRP_MJ_CREATE   filename.log    BAD NETWORK PATH    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Would this show as an OSError 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to record all of the file operations done by Python.exe processes.  If you're on Mac OS X or Solaris, use [DTrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/).  If you're on Linux, use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

Any of those tools will give you a detailed listing of all of the system calls being made, along with their return codes, allowing you to narrow down what's failing and perhaps why.

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating OSError 2 - it only occurs occasionally. I've added procmon pastes above (but only during normal operation and when file is locked). I've set procmon to record events to disk, and will explore this log if I get another OSError 2.

Comment: I saw a "BAD NETWORK PATH" error, which may correspond to an IOError 2 in python. Any way to confirm this?

Comment: @Alex: If you look at the Python documentation, it says in the description of the built-in open() function: "If the file cannot be opened, IOError is raised". The documentation for file objects states: "When a file operation fails for an I/O-related reason, the exception IOError is raised".

Comment: @RolandSmith My mistake, the error I'm trying to discover the source of is an `OSError` (errno 2), not `IOError`

Comment: Errno 2 is ENOENT; "No such file or directory". That looks like a good match for "BAD NETWORK PATH".

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can wrap the code with exception handling (try/except)

A real solution is more complicated - synchronizing the scripts.
This is what I would do:
Write a broker script which listens to commands (UDP or SimpleXMLRPCServer, for example). Other scripts communicate with it. All operations on the shared file are done via the broker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already handling exceptions (or else my scripts wouldn't run longer than a few minutes!). I'm hoping to get some more information about the error - whether it was caused by the file being currently open (which I thought would give a permission error), or if the server is struggling.

Answer (score 0):

How a ftp share was created? how are organized 'open' files proceeding?

a) try to use 'with' according to [pep 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

if it not will work:

b) Try to make your own ftp share server with two methonds - read and
    write. you can implement [non-blocking reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) algorithm.

> Non-blocking algorithms are also safe for use in interrupt handlers:
>   even though the preempted thread cannot be resumed, progress is still
>   possible without it. In contrast, global data structures protected by
>   mutual exclusion cannot safely be accessed in a handler, as the
>   preempted thread may be the one holding the lock.